# Print out lines have value great than 1 with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I was trying to pull out data in a file with any of the value in a line is great than 1. Do you guys know any easy way to do this?

```
awk -F"\t" '{if(($3>1)||($4>1)||($5>1)||($6>1)||($7>1)||($8>1)||($9>1)||($10>1)||($11>1)||($12>1)||($13>1)||($14>1)||($15>1)||($16>1)||($17>1)||($18>1))print$0}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `for` loop in awk instead of writing that many this many conditions:

```
awk -F"\t" '{for(i=3; i<=18; i++){if($i>1){print $0; next;}}}' filename
```

If you wish to comapare with column from `3` to the last column, use `NF` instead of `18` in the loop condition.

Comment: You can start at i=1, and instead of 18 you can use NF. But if there is text fields, they will get printed.

Comment: use `next` instead of `break` this will be faster

Comment: @A.Danischewski I have wrote from `i=3` to `i=18` because OP used that in the condition statement.

Comment: Well done, I was generalizing the NF and probably overlooked the 3 because of the compare to 1 - also you may want to add that if a column has a text value it will get printed - if you don't want that behavior you need to check that the column value is a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'\t' '{f=0; for (i=3;i<=18;i++) if ($i>1) f=1} f' file1.txt
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the `print` statement?

Comment: @Marki555 The `f` at the end prints it if it is 1, as the default action for awk is to print the line.

Comment: To gain minor efficiency: `if ($i>1) {f=1; break}` -- you may save a few microseconds.

Comment: @glennjackman or just remove the variable completely `if ($i>1) {print; break}`

Comment: Yup but I figured execution speed wasn't an issue and I generally avoid anything that unnecessarily forces a nameless change in control flow (goto, break, continue). I've accepted next and nextfile as part of the awk idiom.